# Reading version specific files delta-lake

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, delta-lake

I want to read the delta data after a certain timestamp/version. The logic [here](https://docs.delta.io/latest/delta-batch.html#:%7E:text=Query%20the%20number%20of%20new%20customers%20added%20over%20the%20last%20week.) suggests to read the entire data and read the specific version, and then find the delta. As my data is huge, I would prefer not to read the entire data and if somehow be able to read only the data after certain timestamp/version.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you need to have data after specific time, or snapshot of data at specific time?

Comment: @AlexOtt I would need the data. But what exactly do you mean by snapshot of data?

Comment: Data in Delta are organized by versions - but that's a snapshot of data at given period of time, that may contain different timestamps, etc.

Answer (score 2):

If you need data that have timestamp after some specific date, then you still need to shift through all data.  But Spark & Delta Lake may help here if you organize your data correctly:

- You can have time-based partitions, for example, store data by day/week/month, so when Spark will read data it may read only specific partitions (perform so-called predicate pushdown), for example, `df = spark.read.format("delta").load(...).filter("day > '2021-12-29'")` - this will work not only for Delta, but for other formats as well. Delta Lake may additionally help here because is supports so-called [generated columns](https://docs.delta.io/latest/delta-batch.html#use-generated-columns) where you don't need to create a partition column explicitly, but allow Spark to generate it for you based on other columns
- On top of partitioning, formats like Parquet (and Delta that is based on Parquet) allow to skip reading all data because they maintain the min/max statistics inside the files.  But you will still need to read these files
- On Databricks, Delta Lake has more capabilities for selective read of the data - for example, that min/max statistics that Parquet has inside the file, could be saved into the transaction log, so Delta won't need to open file to check if timestamp in the given range - this technique is called [data skipping](https://docs.databricks.com/delta/optimizations/file-mgmt.html#data-skipping).  Additional performance could come from the [ZOrdering](https://docs.databricks.com/delta/optimizations/file-mgmt.html#z-ordering-multi-dimensional-clustering) of the data that will collocate data closer to each other - that's especially useful when you need to filter by multiple columns

Update 14.04.2022: Data Skipping is also available in OSS Delta, starting with version 1.2.0